# how to print the Variable 'num' in my bash shell

Tags: linux, bash, shell, ubuntu

this is my code :

```
num=2
echo "this is the $numnd"
```

it show :

```
this is the
```

what can i do ,

thanks

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Use braces, like so:

```
num=2
echo "this is the ${num}nd"
```

output:

```
this is the 2nd
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use:

```
echo "this is the ${num}nd"
```